# Buttons not working inside a react component

Tags: reactjs, function

I'm new in the programming area, and I'm trying to build a react web app that has a cart button when it is clicked it shows the products in the cart

My App.js is this

```
import './App.css';
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import Item from "./components/Item";
import AboutUs from "./components/AboutUs";
import {useState} from "react";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";

const products = []
const savedItems = []

function App() {


    const [state, setState] = useState(false);

    const changeState = () =>{
        if (state){
            setState(false);
        } else {
            setState(true)
        }
    }


    const toFalse = () => {
      setState(false);
    }



  return (
    <div className="App">
        <HomePage onChangeState={changeState}/>
        {state? <Cart closeCart={toFalse} onCart={savedItems}/> : ""}
        <h2>Produtos</h2>
        <div className="card-items">
            {products.map(item => (
                <Item key={item.id} imgSrc={item.image} title={item.title} price={item.price.toFixed(2)}/>
            ))}
        </div>
        <AboutUs/>


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in the HomePage component it has button to change the state and hide/show a cart, it is working correctly when i click in the cart icon

```
         <div className="user-cart">
               <FontAwesomeIcon className="user" icon={faUser} size="2x"/>
               <FontAwesomeIcon className="cart" onClick={changeState} icon={faCartShopping} size="2x"/>
         </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Egkf.jpg)

(ignore the portuguese there)

the problem is that sems like that the buttons in the card component did not work

```
import React from "react";
import "./Cart.css"
import ItemOnCart from "./ItemOnCart";
import Button from "./Button";

export const Cart = (props) => {

    if(props.onCart.length === 0){
        return (
            <div className="cart-panel">
                <h1>Sem item no carrinho</h1>
                <Button onClick={props.closeCart}>Fechar</Button>
            </div>
        )
    } else{
        return(
            <div className="cart-panel">
                <h1>No Seu Carrinho</h1>
                <ItemOnCart imgItem={props.onCart[0].image} title={props.onCart[0].title} price={props.onCart[0].price}/>
                <ItemOnCart imgItem={props.onCart[1].image} title={props.onCart[1].title} price={props.onCart[1].price}/>
                <Button onClick={props.closeCart}>Fechar</Button>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Cart
```

when i click in the button "fechar" which is to close it should call the parent function and change de state to false, but it is not doing this, i tried to make the button just show a console.log msg to confirm that it is working but also not working

does it has a better way to do this? I'm still learning react so maybe it has a better option to show and hide the cart area. thx

Comment: Can u provide the code for your button component

Comment: I found the problem but still don't know why I tried with a normal HTML button tag and the click event was working, but with the component Button that I create (to reuse in other parts) the events don't work..

`
import React from "react";
import "./Button.css"
export const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <button className="green-button">{props.children}</button>
    )
}

export default Button
`

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking/calling the function, like so <Button onClick={() => props.closeCart()}>Fechar or for more readability, you could put it in a function

`const handleCloseCart = () => {props.closeCart()};`
and then

```
<Button onClick={handleCloseCart}>Fechar</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions:

```
// App.js
import './App.css';
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import Item from "./components/Item";
import AboutUs from "./components/AboutUs";
import {useState} from "react";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";

function App() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]); // use setProducts to change the state of products
    const [savedItems, setSavedItems] = useState([]); // use setSavedItems to change the state of savedItems

    const [state, setState] = useState(false);

    const changeState = () => setState(!state);
    const closeCart = () => setState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <HomePage onChangeState={changeState}/>
        {state && <Cart closeCart={closeCart} savedItems={savedItems}/>}
        <h2>Produtos</h2>
        <div className="card-items">
            {products.map(item => (
                <Item key={item.id} imgSrc={item.image} title={item.title} price={item.price.toFixed(2)}/>
            ))}
        </div>
        <AboutUs/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// Cart.js
import React from "react";
import "./Cart.css"
import ItemOnCart from "./ItemOnCart";
import Button from "./Button";

export const Cart = ({savedItems, closeCart}) =>  (
    <div className="cart-panel">
        <h1>{savedItems.length === 0 ? "Sem item no carrinho" : "No Seu Carrinho"}</h1>
        {savedItems.map(savedItem => (
        <ItemOnCart imgItem={savedItem.image} title={savedItem.title} price={savedItem.price}/>
        ))}

        <Button onClick={closeCart}>Fechar</Button>
    </div>
);


export default Cart
```

Without more details (code context), it is hard to tell what exactly causes the issue. A good starting point could be the Cart.js component and the `keys` on the elements within the if block.

For more details, see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXJkeZf-4-4